# create custom role in django to employees

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-middleware

I have created a role model for Employee so that employee will be assigned to control 
the overall app based on his/her role. I mean if the role of employee is given can_create_only, then the employee should be able to create inventory, orders, items etc and if employee is given can_create_edit_and_delete, then the employee would be like one of the admin and etc. For this I have designed the model as below but I want to know what is the best way to handle such and why?

Should I go with middleware or decorator way? Can anyone give me an example, please?

```
class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Role'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Roles'


class Employee(models.Model):
    office = models.ForeignKey(
        OfficeSetup, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    designation = models.ForeignKey(Designation, blank=False, null=False)
    section = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentSetup, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=4, choices=GENDER, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        null=True, blank=True, upload_to=upload_employee_image_path)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Employee'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Employees'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When creating an employee by admin, the username, password and email, the admin provides will create a new user instance along with the employee

Answer (score 1):

Django comes with Groups and permissions which provides all most everything you are looking for.
This may help you - [How do I use Django groups and permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778685/how-do-i-use-django-groups-and-permissions)
Django documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/

Comment: Can you show me an example, please? Documentation I felt difficult to understand

Comment: If I am not wrong, the documentation shows setting permission for specific models only but my use case is setting permission for all the models at once