# How to apply/set a permission to an User

Tags: django

I have a `Car` model in my car_store app.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (('can_buy', 'User can buy this car'),)
```

Right now I have a custom `User` model in my accounts app which is:

```
from django.db import models as _models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField()
    ....
    def has_perms(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

and later I would simple make use of [PermissionRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.PermissionRequiredMixin) for my view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import ListView

class CarListView(PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
    permission_required = ('car.can_buy',)
```

**The question is** django does not offer any type of `self.set_perm(self, perm)` or `set_perm(some_user, perm)`? If not, what would be the simplest way to implement it?

Should I simply do something like this?

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    perms = []
    def set_perm(self, perm):
        self.perms.append(perm)
    def has_perm(self, perm):
        return self.perms.count(perm)
```

I couldn't find nothing that describes how to set a perm to an user (except third-party [django-guardian - assign_perm()](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2/userguide/assign.html#assign-obj-perms)). Neither a [Full Example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) from django docs talks about how to set a perm to the User. There's even this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4784936/2953385), but he doesn't talk about setting the perm to the user, but just how to check for a perm.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you don't use `BooleanField` like `is_staff` or sth else?

Comment: Also, there's `groups` in django. You can add/minus authentication for each groups. check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/)

Comment: @seuling, Yes, there's a reason. A project I'm woking on should have two type of users, a Master and an Analyst. The analyst can't access all the urls. Being staff in this case, the analysts would have much power, which they should not.

Comment: Ok. then I think you can use custom backend. I will upload answer